# Xamarin Forms ImageButton - Shadow is not rendering on Android if CornerRadius is non zero

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add shadow to circle ImageButton for Android in Xamarin Forms. I'm doing this according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/imagebutton-drop-shadow).
But shadow is not drawing.

Here is the code:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            ... some page content
        </StackLayout>

        <ImageButton Source="chevron_up" BackgroundColor="Red"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95,0.69,68,68"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    CornerRadius="100"
                    android:ImageButton.IsShadowEnabled="true"
                    android:ImageButton.ShadowColor="Gray"
                    android:ImageButton.ShadowRadius="22">
            <android:ImageButton.ShadowOffset>
                <Size>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>10</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>10</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </Size>
            </android:ImageButton.ShadowOffset>
        </ImageButton>                  
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And result:

[image: shadow not drawn]

When I set CornerRadius to 0 or remove this attribute, then shadow is drawn correctly:

[image: shadow drawn]

There is nothing about this in the docs. Is this a bug? And did soimeone solved this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Custom Renderer** to add Shadow and Corner on the Element .

#### in Android

Creat a xml file in the folder Resource->drawable button_style.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" 
                    android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" 
                    android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using App11.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ImageButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace App11.Droid
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ImageButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ImageButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                this.SetBackground(ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.button_style, null) );
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And in xaml

```
 <ImageButton Source="chevron_up" BackgroundColor="Red"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95,0.69,68,68"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    CornerRadius="100"
                    >
            
        </ImageButton>
```

Comment: @lucas-zhang-msft, thanks! But why such simple thing requires custom renderer? There is no "out-of-box" solution? I'm trying to avoid any custom rendering in our app, because any custom code needs to be maintained

Comment: I will confirm if it is an existing issue . You could use my solution as workaround . If it helps you , don't forget to accept it , which will help more people who has similar issue :)